# incorrect Perl syntax yields incorrect error message

Tags: perl, syntax-error

The following (much stripped-down) code has an obvious error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL=>"all";

my $err_phyle;
my $verb;

sub do_measure
{
  print($error_phyle "xxx");

}

sub dye
{
}

dye "invalid verb \"$verb\"";
```

You'd expect the error message to be:

```
Global symbol "$error_phyle" requires explicit package name at example.pl line 11.
example.pl had compilation errors.
```

... but it's actually ...

```
String found where operator expected at example.pl line 19, near "dye "invalid verb \"$verb\"""
```

(Note that the second error message doesn't add "example.pl had compilation errors.".)

In the real program, the error message pointed to a line hundreds of lines of code away from the actual error. Incorrect error messages, pointing to the wrong line, can lead to much merriment trying to track down the syntax error.

I can "fix" this in the above program by surrounding the argument of the call to function `dye` with parentheses, and I guess I'll go through the program and do this. But is this a bug in Perl, or (as is more likely the case) am I missing something about how Perl works?

Comment: Running your code with Perl 5.24.1, I see both compilation errors.

Comment: Dave, that's puzzling. There should be only one compilation error. Maybe they made a stab at fixing the bug (since my Perl 5.20.3), but didn't do it thoroughly enough. Certainly 5.24.1 is an improvement, because one *is* pointed to the correct line.

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa You can get more information about the errors by adding [`use diagnostics`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html)

Comment: I get the same behavior as @DaveCross: It seems like the compiler tries to continue after it finds undefined global symbol `$error_phyle` then it bails out at `"dye"` at line 19. But since the warnings are fatal, it should not try to continue at all?? So this is strange.. ( I am also using 5.24.1)

Comment: Håkon, the `use diagnostics` suggestion is useful because with even my ancient version of Perl it shows both error messages; that's not as clean as showing only the one that is true, but it saves me from having to rip apart my code to find the error, which can take quite a while. So that really solves my problem. Write it up as a solution, and I'll approve it, if you're interested in points.

Comment: See the documentation of [strictures](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strictures) for warnings you shouldn't make fatal.

Comment: @ikegami This is quite useful. I once was writing a program where I wanted to call a function recursively more than 100 deep, and Perl told me not to do that. Knowing what I know now, I could have recursed to my heart's content. As it was, I just threw up in disgust and did it in Lisp instead. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) pragma to get more information about the errors.

> The `diagnostics` Pragma
>
> This module extends the terse diagnostics normally emitted by both the
>   perl compiler and the perl interpreter (from running perl with a -w
>   switch or use warnings ), augmenting them with the more explicative
>   and endearing descriptions found in `perldiag`. Like the other pragmata,
>   it affects the compilation phase of your program rather than merely
>   the execution phase. To use in your program as a pragma, merely invoke
>
> ```
> use diagnostics;
> ```
>
> at the start (or near the start) of your program. 
>   (Note that this does enable perl's -w flag.) Your whole compilation
>   will then be subject(ed :-) to the enhanced diagnostics. These still
>   go out STDERR.

Based on your comments: this can also make older versions of perl show both error messages, which could save you some debugging effort to find the location of the real error.

Comment: I just note in passing the use in the documentation you quote of the word "pragmata". "Pragma" isn't found in all dictionaries (not even the online Oxford); not all of the dictionaries in which I found it are particularly technical dictionaries, but *no* dictionaries in which I found it list a plural for it. "Pragmata" is a cool plural form. The author of that sentence in the documentation probably knows his Greek.

Answer (score 6):

The root cause of this issue is that perl's (yacc-based) parser tries to recover and continue after errors. The original idea behind this strategy is that running a compiler used to be a slow and expensive task, so you want it to catch as many errors as possible in a single run, not just the first error. This is why perl queues up errors encountered during parsing before giving up and printing them all at once.

However, there's an unfortunate interaction with fatal warnings. The compiler can emit warnings at compile time, and fatalizing a warning makes it throw an exception. So if the parser is in error recovery mode and encounters a fatal warning, an exception is thrown and all the queued actual errors are lost.

The `String found where operator expected` message is a warning (category `syntax`). By fatalizing all warnings you've turned it into an exception that immediately aborts parsing, losing all preceding errors. (By the way, fatalizing all warnings is a bad idea: See [`perldoc strictures`](https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures#CATEGORY-SELECTIONS) for which warning categories are unsafe to fatalize.)

You can see that something isn't quite right even without fatalizing warnings: The `String found ...` message has a line number of 19, yet it appears before the syntax error in line 11. This is because warnings are emitted immediately, not queued like parse errors.

This problem was reported as [bug #122966](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=122966) and fixed in perl 5.22. Now fatal warnings thrown during parsing are treated like parse errors and queued the same way. (As a side effect, it also makes the error messages appear in the right order: The first error is reported first.)

So yes, this behavior is a bug in perl, but one that was already fixed in a later release.

Comment: This is most interesting, thank you. I would point out, though, that it doesn't seem (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the "error" on line 19 is an actual error; fixing the error on line 11 makes the sample Perl chunk compile with no syntax errors. I could understand it if the first error were a misplaced parenthesis or something, because that can fry the syntax for the rest of the compilation, but the error on line 11 was nothing like that.

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa After the error on line 11, perl goes into error recovery mode. In this mode, `sub` definitions are "neutered" and subroutines aren't added to the symbol table, so `sub dye {}` is effectively a no-op. That's why in the last line `dye` can't be resolved and `dye "..."` is a parse error.

Comment: Fascinating. I think that explains why putting parentheses around the argument to `dye` eliminates the error notification for line 19. It's conversations like this that help me use Perl in a mode which is less superstitious ("it just works if you do it this way, so do it this way") and more knowledge-based.